# How to get speed and distance to work with CLLocation in Xcode 10?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I use the latest version of Xcode and am currently trying to build an app for the latest version of IOS. The app is an activity tracking program which requires speed, distance, time and location. Location and time work fine but the code for speed and distance isn't working. The UILabels won't change.

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan =  MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let reigon:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myLocation, span: span)
    map.setRegion(reigon, animated: true)
    self.map.showsUserLocation =  true
    self.map.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading

    //Speed and distance
    let mps = location.speed
    let km = mps * 3.6
    if watch.isRunning {
        print(String(format: "%.2f", km))
        speedText.text = String(format: "%.2f", km)

        if startLocation == nil {
            startLocation = locations.first
        } else if let location = locations.last {
            traveledDistance += lastLocation.distance(from: location)
            print("Traveled Distance:",  traveledDistance)

            let dist = traveledDistance * 3.6

            speedText.text = String(format: "%.2f", dist)

            print("Straight Distance:", startLocation.distance(from: locations.last!))
        }
        lastLocation = locations.last

    } else {
        distanceText.text = String("00.00")
        speedText.text = String("00.00")
        return
    }

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    if (error as? CLError)?.code == .denied {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        manager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
}
```

This is my full code...

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ExcersiseViewController: UIViewController {

var timerText: UILabel!
var speedText: UILabel!
var distanceText: UILabel!

var action: UIButton!
var map: MKMapView!
let watch = Stopwatch()
let saveSystem = SaveCompleted()

var startLocation: CLLocation!
var lastLocation: CLLocation!
var traveledDistance: Double = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self as? CLLocationManagerDelegate
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    manager.distanceFilter = 10

    let lightGreyColor = UIColor(red: 68/255, green: 68/255, blue: 68/255, alpha: 1)

    view.backgroundColor = .black

    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let width = bounds.size.width
    let height = bounds.size.height

    map = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: height - (height / 2), width: width, height: height - (height / 2)))
    map.showsUserLocation =  true
    map.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading

    action = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: width, height: 50))
    action.backgroundColor = lightGreyColor
    action.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    action.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startStop), for: .touchUpInside)
    if watch.isRunning {
        action.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
    } else {
        action.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
    }

    timerText = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: height / 7, width: width, height: 50))
    timerText.text = "00:00:00"
    timerText.textAlignment = .center
    timerText.textColor = .white
    timerText.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 60)

    speedText = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: height / 3, width: width, height: 50))
    speedText.text = "00.00"
    speedText.textAlignment = .left
    speedText.textColor = .white
    speedText.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 60)

    distanceText = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: height / 3, width: width, height: 50))
    distanceText.text = "00.00"
    distanceText.textAlignment = .right
    distanceText.textColor = .white
    distanceText.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 60)

    self.view.addSubview(distanceText)
    self.view.addSubview(speedText)
    self.view.addSubview(timerText)
    self.view.addSubview(action)
    self.view.addSubview(map)

}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

let manager = CLLocationManager()
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan =  MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let reigon:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myLocation, span: span)
    map.setRegion(reigon, animated: true)
    self.map.showsUserLocation =  true
    self.map.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading

    //Speed and distance
    let mps = location.speed
    let km = mps * 3.6
    if watch.isRunning {
        print(String(format: "%.2f", km))
        speedText.text = String(format: "%.2f", km)

        if startLocation == nil {
            startLocation = locations.first
        } else if let location = locations.last {
            traveledDistance += lastLocation.distance(from: location)
            print("Traveled Distance:",  traveledDistance)

            let dist = traveledDistance * 3.6

            speedText.text = String(format: "%.2f", dist)

            print("Straight Distance:", startLocation.distance(from: locations.last!))
        }
        lastLocation = locations.last

    } else {
        distanceText.text = String("00.00")
        speedText.text = String("00.00")
        return
    }

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    if (error as? CLError)?.code == .denied {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        manager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
}

@objc func updateElapsedTimeLabel(timer : Timer) {
    if watch.isRunning {
        let hours = Int(watch.elapsedTime/60/60)
        let minutes = Int(watch.elapsedTime.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)/60)
        let seconds = Int(watch.elapsedTime.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
        timerText.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}

@objc func startStop() {
    if watch.isRunning {
        watch.stop()
        action.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
        //Save code

        let time = timerText.text
        let distance = distanceText.text

        if time != "" && distance != "" {
            saveSystem.runFromView(info: "Activity data: Time taken: \(time), Distance travelled: \(distance)")
            timerText.text = "00:00:00"
            distanceText.text = "00.00"
            speedText.text = "00.00"
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "There was an error saving the activity. We are sorry for the inconvinience. Please try again or contact support if the error persists.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
    } else {
        watch.start()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ExcersiseViewController.updateElapsedTimeLabel(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        action.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
    }
}

}
```

I also have my stopwatch script here... Note: This part works and the speed code used to on Xcode 9.

```
import Foundation

class Stopwatch {

private var startTime : NSDate?
var elapsedTime: TimeInterval {
    if let startTime = self.startTime {
        return -startTime.timeIntervalSinceNow
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
var isRunning: Bool {
    return startTime != nil
}
func start() {
    startTime = NSDate()
}
func stop() {
    startTime = nil
}
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on the problem? I've add the Mapkit and CoreLocation packages as well as set the proper usage description. Note: I have created the whole view programmatically so it isn't linked to storyboards.

Comment: Are you getting values in `dist`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `CLLocationManagerDelegate`  to your View Controller

So Replace

```
manager.delegate = self as? CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

With

```
manager.delegate = self
```

and  add `CLLocationManagerDelegate` here

```
class ExcersiseViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
 ....
}
```

protocol [image]

Comment: is not a answer related to the question, I am not seen any changes from question and your answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik There is change `manager.delegate = self as? CLLocationManagerDelegate` See this

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ViewController has not confirm the  `CLLocationManagerDelegate` so `self as? CLLocationManagerDelegate` would be nil

Comment: but questioner mentioned `Location and time work` works fine